# Cannot find symbol symbol : variable PROXIMITY_ON_WAKE?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a ROM for Android and everything is going smooth, but then i added Proximity Wake feature from CM and got this error:

```
packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/DisplaySettings.java:148: cannot find symbol symbol  : 
variable advancedPrefs location: class com.android.settings.DisplaySettings         
advancedPrefs.removePreference(findPreference(KEY_PROXIMITY_WAKE));         ^ 
packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/DisplaySettings.java:149: cannot find symbol symbol  : 
variable PROXIMITY_ON_WAKE location: class android.provider.Settings.System         
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.PROXIMITY_ON_WAKE, 1);


^ Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile
with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 2 errors
```

when i open up the file i find this lines:

```
advancedPrefs.removePreference(findPreference(KEY_PROXIMITY_WAKE));             
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.PROXIMITY_ON_WAKE, 1);
```

The error states that it cannot find a symbol, what is wrong?

Comment: The errors state it pretty clearly: the compiler cannot find the variables `advancedPrefs` and `PROXIMITY_ON_WAKE`. If you'll show us the relevant class/es we might be able to find the reason *why* it's not recognized.

Comment: can you be mor specific?

Comment: Exactly! if you want more help you'll have to be *more specific* with the data you're providing in your question. You don't really expect me to guess how your code looks like, do you?

Comment: where do i find these clas/es?

Comment: If you can't find your classes you're in a bigger problem than this question. And that's not the kind of problem you can get remote help for. Sorry.

Comment: Settings.System class does not have any constant with name PROXIMITY_ON_WAKE. Where did you get it from (code)?

Comment: From the CyanogenMod Github